# Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*.py"

Tags: python, vim

I have a problem with my vim config...

This error occurs when opening python (.py) files:

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*.py":
E20: Mark not set
```

When opening for example html (.html) or ruby (.rb) files, the error does not occur.

Here is my vim config. The plugins are all installed.

```
""" VUNDLE """
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" plugins
Plugin 'valloric/youcompleteme'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plugin 'shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim'
Plugin 'quramy/tsuquyomi'
"Plugin 'Shougo/vimproc.vim'
Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on



""" CONFIG """
set history=200 "command history

set so=7 "add 7 lines when moving up/down

set hlsearch "highlight search results
set showmatch "highlight matching brackets

set ruler
set relativenumber

syntax enable
set encoding=utf8
set ffs=unix,dos,mac "unix as standard file type

set expandtab
set smarttab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indent
set nowrap "Wrap lines

set laststatus=2

" whitespace
set list
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<

set nobackup
set nowb
set noswapfile

" NERDTree
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
"autocmd vimenter * NERDTree

" NERDTreeTabs
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup=1
map <Leader>n <plug>NERDTreeTabsToggle<CR>

au FileType php setl ofu=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
au FileType ruby,eruby setl ofu=rubycomplete#Complete
au FileType html,xhtml setl ofu=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
au FileType css setl ofu=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
au FileType python setl ofu=pythoncomplete#Complete

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py, *.php, *.rb, *.html, *.js, *.ts, *.md
    \ set tabstop=4 |
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4 |
    \ set textwidth=79 |
    \ set expandtab |
    \ set autoindent |
    \ set fileformat=unix


au BufNewFile,BufRead *.css, *.scss, *.json
    \ set tabstop=2 |
    \ set softtabstop=2 |
    \ set shiftwidth=2 |
    \ set textwidth=79 |
    \ set expandtab |
    \ set autoindent |
    \ set fileformat=unix

let g:ycm_python_binary_path = 'python'

if !exists("g:ycm_semantic_triggers")
  let g:ycm_semantic_triggers = {}
endif

" TypeScript plugin tsuquyomi
let g:ycm_semantic_triggers['typescript'] = ['.']
let g:tsuquyomi_import_curly_spacing = 0
let g:tsuquyomi_single_quote_import = 1
map <C-i> :TsuImport<CR>

hi Pmenu ctermbg=green
```

I did change the line with "BufNewFile" into different ways (1 `set` command, multiple `set` commands, with pipes, without pipes, with backslashes, without backslashes, etc.) but nothing helped.

Does anyone know what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `:au BufRead *.py` in your `.vimrc`? Does the problem go away when you comment it out? I think this is caused by some (filetype) plugin. What's the output of `:au BufRead *.py`?

Comment: Oh, and you can put all options after _one_ `:set` command: `set ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 ...` With this, you might not need to break the line.

Comment: @IngoKarkat if I remove just the `*.py` extension from the line with the `BufRead` it does not throw an error when opening a python-file.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's hard to notice (I had to look twice), but **the problem is the spaces between the patterns** in the `:autocmd` definition:

The syntax is

> ```
> :au[tocmd] [group] {event} {pat} [nested] {cmd}
> ```

`:help {pat}` shows that there must not be whitespace between individual patterns.

#### Example

```
:au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py, *.php, *.rb, *.html, *.js, *.ts, *.md echomsg 'test'

:au BufRead *.py
--- Auto-Commands ---
filetypedetect  BufRead
    *.py      setf python
BufRead
    *.py      *.php, *.rb, *.html, *.js, *.ts, *.md echomsg 'test'
```

As you can see, Vim only recognizes the *first* pattern, and takes all following as (Ex) commands!

The `:*` command executes the contents of a register (probably rubbish), and that causes the `E20` error you've seen (probably because there's the `'` character in the register).

#### Fix

Drop the whitespace. As I've already commented, you can also skip repeating the `:set` commands for each option.

```
:au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py,*.php,*.rb,*.html,*.js,*.ts,*.md ...
```